# How to login user with Meteor in Server side after Receive A callback from IDP

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor, passport.js, passport-saml

I need authenticate a user using passport-saml v2.0 and login after the authenticaton callback successful responds to IDP post request.

I’am using React in front-end with flow router and Picker in back-end.

I Start the authentication in client side when i click in a button and this create a window with make a request to /auth/saml.

The code work, and my user is successful added to mongodb, but now, after the userHandler function return the userId and the token i want to use Meteor.loginWithToken to login, but this function don’t work in server side.

**The main problem is use the user information retrived by the IDP in callback function and login using Meteor with that information.**

Server side: Code to initiate the authentication using passport js and passport-saml strategy

```
import { Picker} from 'meteor/meteorhacks:picker';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import passport from 'passport';
import saml from 'passport-saml';
import expressSession from 'express-session';

Picker.middleware(bodyParser.json());
Picker.middleware(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
Picker.middleware(cookieParser());
Picker.middleware(expressSession({
  secret: 'secret', 
  resave: false, 
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));

var samlStrategy = new saml.Strategy({
    callbackUrl: process.env.ROOT_URL + '/login/callback', //call back in service provider to handle with the IDP response
    entryPoint: 'http://localhost:8080/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php', //link for IDP
    issuer: 'saml-poc', //id da entidade provedora
    identifierFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress', //formato requisitado pela entidade
    decryptionPvk: process.env.CERTPVK,
    privateCert: process.env.CERTPVK,
    cert: process.env.IDPKEY,
    validateInResponseTo: false,
    disableRequestedAuthnContext: true,
}, function(profile, done) {
    return done(null, profile);
});

passport.use('samlStrategy', samlStrategy);
Picker.middleware(passport.initialize({}));
Picker.middleware(passport.session({}));

//serialize the user
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log('-----------------------------');
  console.log('serialize user');
  console.log(user);
  console.log('-----------------------------');
  done(null, user);
});

//deserialize
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log('-----------------------------');
  console.log('deserialize user');
  console.log(user);
  console.log('-----------------------------');
  done(null, user);
});

Picker.route('/auth/saml', 
  function(params, req, res, next) {
    console.log('Start login handler');
    passport.authenticate('samlStrategy', {
      session: false,
    }, 
    function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error1");
        return next(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        console.log("Error2");
        return res.json(401, {
            error: 'Auth Error!'
        });
      }
    }
    )(req, res, next);
  }
);

Picker.route('/auth/callback',
  function (params, req, res, next) {
    console.log('-----------------------------');
    console.log('/Start login callback ');
    passport.authenticate('samlStrategy', {
      session: false,
  },
  async function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.json(401, {
          error: 'Auth Error!'
      });
    }

    const {userId, token} = await userHandler(user);

    res.write("<script>window.close();</script>");
    res.flushHeaders();
    res.end('Sucess');

  })(req, res, next);
});

const userHandler = (user) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  let usr = Accounts.findUserByEmail(user.email);
  const company = "company";
  const profile = { name: "Vinicius França" };
  const stampedToken = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken();

  if(!usr){
    Meteor.call('adminUser_addNewUser', user.email, null, profile, company, "user", undefined, undefined, true, (err,res) => {
      if(!res){
        SweetAlert('OPS...', 'Error', 'error');
      }
      Accounts.findUserByEmail(user.email).then((_usr) => {
        Accounts._insertLoginToken(_usr._id, stampedToken);
        resolve({userId: _usr._id, token: stampedToken});
      })
    });
  } else {
    Accounts._clearAllLoginTokens(usr._id);
    Accounts._insertLoginToken(usr._id, stampedToken);
    resolve({userId: usr._id, token: stampedToken});
  }
});
```

Client side:

```
logginSAML() {
    this.setState({logginSSO: true});
    let authWindow = window.open(
      window.location.href + "/auth/saml",
      "Window SSO",
      "resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,status=yes",
      "height=1000px",
      "width=100px",
      "_blank"
    );
    const _this = this;

    window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = (e) => {
      //is not working
      //call login with token here
      _this.setState({logginSSO: false});
      console.log('q loucura man');
      e.returnValue = '';
      delete e['returnValue'];
    };
  }
```

Comment: This a lot of code to read. Can you narrow it down to the core of the problem?

Comment: @Jankapunkt i put all the code because i dont now if my aproach is the best way to authenticate a user with saml and login with him using Meteor. The main problem like i say in the post is the Meteor.loginWithToken cannot be in the server, so how i can login user with Meteor using my aproach?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using BroadCastChannel from javascript to send user information as workaround, consequently, loged in client side using Meteor methods.